# Delete system file from mysql command

Tags: mysql, database-administration

I have created some file from mysql command i.e. **select * into outfile '/tmp/abc.csv' from abc;** .This file has ownership of mysql.mysql i.e. no other user is able to remove this file. I don`t have superuser privileges; I am able to edit, add and delete content but not the entire file.

Is there any way that it can be removed from mysql command i.e. from mysql user. or from mysql terminal.

Thanks,

Nitesh Kumar

Comment: I have not tried any thing so far..I really don`t know how and from where to start..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more details as to which OS you are talking about it's hard to say exactly, but your best bet is to look in the Event Log as these should be logged

When the W32Time service changes the time it should log a entry in the System eventlog, and in the details will specify the user that changed it.

It will either be a interactive user (DOMAIN\user) or as the 'System' user which would be from NTP updating the time automatically.

Comment: I have got Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard . I agree with you completely but the issue is it is not logging any thing related to this in event log. How can I force explicitly to event log to log such event???